# How do you get an if, then formula to calculate one of the answers?

Tags: if-statement

I am trying to have a cell calculate the following, but I can't get it do the C5*$15 forumula, it just puts that info into the cell =IF(C5>8,"$125","C5*$15").  Please advise.

Comment: Is this an ms-excel question?

Comment: sounds like you are using some kind of a spread sheet? if you need help - try helping yourself by asking a full question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from around `"C5*$15"`. That's a string literal, so it will be printed exactly instead of evaluated in the FALSE case. You can also remove the $ and just use cell formatting to print the result as a dollar amount.

```
=IF(C5 > 8, 125, C5*15)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're working with numbers, don't use double quotes or dollar signs. Use numbers. Cell formatting will handle adding the currency symbol if your cell is formatted to be currency.

This works perfectly for me:

```
=IF(C5 > 8, 125, C5 * 15)
```